# LinqToSql: ExecuteQuery an ExecuteQuery-result?

Tags: vb.net, linq, linq-to-sql

I use this code to get all customers from my database...

```
Dim customerResult = db.ExecuteQuery(Of VIEW_customers)("SELECT * FROM TOPL_Customers").ToList
```

Now that I have all customers fetched from the database, I want to run a "filter" query against  customerResult - how do I do that?

Was hoping for something like this...

```
Dim filterResult = customerResult.ExecuteQuery(Of VIEW_customers)("SELECT * WHERE active=1").ToList
```

Any suggestions? I don't want to query the database twice.

I need to use a string as a search query because it's dynamic.

Thanks

Comment: Can't you send the filter query to the database to get the filtered results? e.g. join both the queries

Comment: Sorry for not being clear. My filter is dynamic and I don't know upfront wich fields the users will filter. I've updated my question.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var filteredResult = from a in customerResult
                     //Add suitable filter condition based on column values
                     where a.Active == 1
                     select a;
```

Comment: Sorry for not being clear. My filter is dynamic and I don't know upfront which fields the users will filter.

Comment: Even if it is dynamic once you have the result from database you can build the WHERE clause expression based on user inputs. I am assuming you will be checking the columns values against user inputs which can be built dynamically.

Comment: Well I don't know the filtered columns up front ... mayby user will filter ... "WHERE name LIKE '%peter%'" ... and another user will filter ... "WHERE name LIKE '%peter%' AND age > 30" ...  So I can't "hardcode" the filter - I have to build it dynamic and run it against my customerResult.

Comment: Sorry if I was not clear. My point was that you don't know the number of filters upfront but you do the total number of fields to be worked on right? So may be you need to loop through all the rows in result and check if a particular filter was provided by the user e.g. Name, and then match the row with that name. And so on for all the filters provided. But the best approach would be to do this in database in a single query. I can add the code for looping if you think that will help.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming here that VIEW_customers represents your model for the result set.

You can use `Expressions` to build up a series of filters and then join them together to create a single, dynamic where clause to run against your result set.

```
Expression<Func<VIEW_customers, bool>> predicate1 = x => x.someField == 'something';
Expression<Func<VIEW_customers, bool>> predicate2 = x => x.otherField == 'something else';
```

Then you can join them together with `.And` or `.Or` as appropriate:

```
Expression<Func<VIEW_customers, bool>> combinedPredicate = predicate1.And(predicate2);
```

You can chain any number of these together; it's boolean logic (basically think of each additional clause as being wrapped by a set of parenthesis).  When you're ready to consume the predicate, compile it and run it like a normal `.Where` clause.

```
Func<VIEW_customers, bool> compiledPredicate = combinedPredicate.Compile();
var results = customerResult.Where(compiledPredicate);
```